Could a homework policy be added to the help centre?
It common now on the science sites to include a homework policy that can be pointed to for (the many) new users that visit with unreferenced queries which lack any prior research.
A sample text is the one on our Biology site which I've tweaked for our use if though appropriate:

Medicalsciences.se can be a great place to get help and advice with
university and school assignments, however we ask that you take the
time to read through these tips before posting your question.
What is a homework question?
A request for help with an assignment Asking for help after exam
feedback - i.e. "Why was this marked incorrect?" A question that
addresses a basic concept that may seem trivial to medical
professionals. Any question that meets these requirements should be
tagged with homework in addition to other appropriate tags.
What should I do before I ask the question?
Research it yourself - even if you try and can't find the answer or
understand the concept you need you can then include what you have
found out yourself in the question. Search the site to see if
something similar has been asked before. How should I ask my question?
Give full details of the problem. Include details of how you have
attempted to form a solution. We will not do your homework assignments
for you but we will point you in the right direction if you have made
the effort to research the topic first. Use logical and clear
formatting as this will increase your chances of getting an answer.
For example, include tasks from your assignment in blockquotes.

In addition, an appropriate tag should be created with a description like this sample, again adapted from biology.se:

This tag indicates that the question is likely based on a home
assignment in medical-related university or high school courses or is
about an elementary concept that may seem trivial to medical
professionals. Please see the homework policy before asking
homework questions.

